# ruby where to define structs

Tags: ruby, struct, idioms

I know I can define new structs in ruby by doing

```
Person = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name)
```

What I'm wondering is what is the appropriate place to define this struct (and other structs I'll be using). `Person` will be used throughout the system. In other languages such as Java, I would typically define `Person` as another class, but with this inline definition in Ruby, where is the correct place to define it so it is available to the entire system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define it anywhere really. Just make sure to require the file wherever needed

**EDIT**
If you want some structure, it will be nice to have a folder where you define the structs and classes you need and require all files in that folder inside your app

Comment: Is it typical to have a file with multiple structs (and only structs) in there, or are they usually defined 1 per file?

Comment: rails has the convention of one class per file. coming from the the rails world, this is how I structured my source; and it does help to know where a _definition_ is. but you may have multiple structs in one file.